# How do I add something to the array instead of replacing it? PHP

Tags: php

I filling to the array with foreach, I can't figure out how not to replace the value, but assign a new one

```
$class_groups[one] = array('one');
$class_groups[one] = array('two');
$class_groups[two] = array('three');


var_dump($class_groups)
```

Output

```
array(2) { ["one"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "two" } ["two"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "three" } }
```

What I want to get:

```
array(2) { ["one"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "one" [1]=> string(3) "two" } ["two"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "three" } }
```

Comment: [dos and donts](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.donts) In case you are using undefined constants to index into the array.

Comment: In your example you want to push the value onto the array at index `'one'`. Also in the same documentation I commented. Thus: `$class_groups['one'][] = 'two';`

Comment: Or if the problem is complexer you can use [array_merge](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) merging the two arrays together.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Both of these snippets produce your desired output:

```
$class_groups['one'] = [ array('one'), array('two') ];
$class_groups['two'] = array('three');
```

OR

```
$class_groups['one'][] = array('one');
$class_groups['one'][] = array('two');
$class_groups['two'] = array('three');
```

Answer (score -2):

With line two in your example you are replacing the value assigned in line one. You have two possibilities:

```
$class_groups['one'][] = 'one';
$class_groups['one'][] = 'two';
$class_groups['two'] = array('three');
```

Or:

```
$class_groups['one'] = array('one', 'two');
$class_groups['two'] = array('three');
```